# WSO2 DAS Empty data in stream

Tags: wso2, esb, wso2-bam

I'm starting to use WSO2 DAS to publish some data from WSO2 ESB for monitoring purpose.

I configured the stream on both sides (ESB/DAS) but when I send the data to the DAS I just get an empty row in the DAS database. I checked both parameter names and I checked the XPath expressions in ESB and everything seems OK. Obviously I'm missing something.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I've been talking with WSO2 support, the proble was that using the "bam" mediator does not work with the DAS.
You have to use "publish event" mediator + sink in the ESB and the stream/receiver on the DAS. With that, no problem: data is correctly sent.